# Can TDengine database adjust the `keep` argument adaptively？

Tags: tdengine

I'm using TDengine database. I have a scene, the data cannot exceed 500GB on each machine. So I hope when the data collected reach some threshold value, TDengine can remove some historical data.

I know there is an argument called 'keep', but the value cannot be determined precisely.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

TDengine is a time series database, so its keep policy is based on time, similar to almost all other time series databases.

To solve your problem, you'd better know how much data is generated one day in your system, let's call it N, then divide 500GB by N, you can get the maximum days of data you can keep in your system, let's call it M, then set keep to a number a little bit lower than M.